# An svn repo moved to git. I was using git

Tags: git, git-svn

So the situation is this.

- There was an svn repository (open source)
- I cloned it using git-svn into my own repo (lets called B) and diverged a little, owner of svn repo wasnt interested in getting PR at the time.
- Finally the owner of the svn repo does move to git, lets call this repo C. The owner didn't keep the history when importing :( [FYI I did offer to transfer ownership of my repo]

**I need to be able to inform my repo (B) that now we can pull from C from now on?** Is there any good way to do this? I had a look at graph but found it pretty confusing.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to rebase your work onto the new history from the owner's repo, since your history won't match his since you both did two separate imports from SVN into Git. So add the owner's repo as a remote, fetch, and use `git rebase --onto <owner's commit> <your old base commit> <your branch>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep both remotes in your repository, it's just that you'll have two independent branches in your repo: the git-svn old one, and the new one (since the new one won't be matched against git-svn one).

You'll be able to diff between them, push and pull to C, and rebase your current branches on it.

Just change the remote URL and fetch it:

```
git remote set-url origin <new-url>
git fetch origin
```

You'll want to keep track of last SVN head with a tag, also.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
git remote add neworigin /path/to/origin
git fetch neworigin
git checkout -b newmaster neworigin/master
git checkout master
git rebase newmaster
git branch --set-upstream master neworigin/master
```

I've not attempted this before in your situation and don't have any easy way of testing it but it seems like this should work. If you reach that point and it all goes well you can remove the old remote and do a bit of house keeping like so (assuming the old remote was named "origin"):

```
git remote rm origin
git remote rename neworigin origin
```

Given that this is untested it may be worth attempting this on a disposable branch or a copy of the local repo.